# Android ConnectivityManager callbacks not working

Tags: android, android-connectivitymanager

I need to check the current internet availability.
Since many of the old calls are deprecated I use the

```
ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback()
```

approach with a callback.
However, when implementing something like this:

```
private val connectivityCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
      override fun onAvailable(network: Network) {
            Log.debug("Available $network")
      }

      override fun onLost(network: Network) {
            Log.debug("Lost $network")
      }
}
```

the onAvailable is not working reliable.

This causes issues when working with WIFI and Cellular networks at the same time. When the users are deactivating wifi I get the callback for the lost network of the wifi. But I don not get an Available call for the cellular network. Thus my app is believing I have no internet.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Since the function used to register *ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback()* isn't provided, I'm assuming, based on callbacks got,

```
registerNetworkCallback (NetworkRequest request, 
                ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback networkCallback)
```

is used to register the callback.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkRequest

In the starting paragraphs, difference between *registerNetworkCallback* and *requestNetwork* is stated,

For NetworkRequest,

```
val networkRequest = NetworkRequest.Builder()
        .addCapability(NetworkCapabilities.NET_CAPABILITY_INTERNET)
        .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
        .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
        .build()
```

**registerNetworkCallback** will receive callbacks for all the networks matching.

*onAvailable* is called twice if both are connected. When wifi is lost, *onLost* is called only for wifi and technically mobile data hasn't been lost, *onAvailable* is not called again.

**requestNetwork** will receive callback for the best possible network and system keeps up with the use case.

When both are connected, *onAvailable* is called for wifi, as system determines it is better. When wifi is lost, *onLost* is called, and now best possible network is mobile data, so *onAvailable* is called for mobile data.

Either *requestNetwork* or *registerDefaultNetworkCallback* can be used for the use case mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun register() {
    //Internet control with NetworkCallback on Android 9 and higher versions
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        val connectivityManager =
            mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE) as ConnectivityManager
        //Checking the internet absence status when the application is first opened
        if (connectivityManager.activeNetwork == null) {
            result(false, null)
        }

        //OnLost method works when there is internet, then when internet is turned off            networkCallback = object : ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback() {
            override fun onLost(network: Network) {
                super.onLost(network)
                result(false, null)
            }

            //Detection of whether the network where the internet comes from is Wifi or mobile location (Cellular)
            override fun onCapabilitiesChanged(
                network: Network,
                networkCapabilities: NetworkCapabilities
            ) {
                super.onCapabilitiesChanged(network, networkCapabilities)
                when {
                    networkCapabilities.hasTransport(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI) -> {
                        // WIFI
                        result(true, ConnectionType.Wifi)
                    }

                    else -> {
                        // CELLULAR
                        result(true, ConnectionType.Cellular)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        connectivityManager.registerDefaultNetworkCallback(networkCallback)
    } else {
        //Internet control with Intent Filter on Android 8 and below
        val intentFilter = IntentFilter()
        intentFilter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE")
        mContext.registerReceiver(networkChangeReceiver, intentFilter)
    }
}
```

I found a result like this, maybe it will help you